# How do I send formated html emails?

Tags: javascript, forms, html-email

I have a page where a user can "share" the page with other people. I want the email to be formatted with html.

I'm using javascript to send the email. Any Idea's?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're using an html anchor element with the mailto: scheme.

To be able to reliably send formatted HTML in an email-client-independent way, you need to send via serverside code of some sorts.

Comment: Yes, that script is essentially the same. It uses the mailto: scheme.